# What are alternatives for GUIDs for key generation when central server is not possible?

Tags: algorithm, key, distributed-computing, bitcoin

I am looking for alternative to GUIDs for key generation in a distributed app. For example supposed I have Bob, James, and Jack all running a bug tracking application on their desktop where they can do thing like create bug tickets ala JIRA, or Bugzilla ... etc. When a ticket is created it is assigned a number such as T-1, T-2, T-3, T-4 ... etc. Tickets need to have a stable ID and should be creatable without having to consult a central server.

I understand that this is what GUID's are really good for but it in my case displaying a GUID in a UI is ugly people can't just copy and paste it and discuss it on a phone call, I really want integers or some sort of short string that is easy to talk about read in one glance .. etc.

Is there a way to use the bitcoin block chain as some sort of counter?

Comment: how many ID's will be there at once ? you can create id string ranges (big enough) for each distributed node and when they are no more used then use them again ... but that will need id usage map and the entries in your database/table must have limited duration ... if they are forever remembered then you have unlimited id range which is not doable in this way ....

Answer (score 1):

You may evaluate the approach taken by git. They use sha1 hash of commit information. And then abbreviate IDs are allowed which are much shorter and easier to read\transfer manually.
Having the number of bugs in your tracker is not going to reach millions that should be sufficient. Once it is you'll just need a longer abbreviation.

There seem to be plenty info around on how git calculates hash IDs and abbreviates them.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly how UUIDv1 works - it's "just" putting together the mac address and a very exact timestamp + maybe some additional integer. As your mac address should be unique (unless you've fiddled with it) and there are only so many UUIDs one computer can generate within a nano second, the resulting ID will be unique.

This is a very general and uninformed way to create IDs. If you'd implement a version of it yourself for your specific use case you could get much smaller IDs.

Assuming you can identify each node with a bug tracking system with a simple and unique string - for instance "Bob", "James", "Jack" - and you can create unique continuous integers within each node, you could combine those two and have IDs like "Bob-1", "James-12", ...

As you can see, actually there has to be again one central point, which will assign the unique strings, however depending on the number of nodes and how long they stay within the system, this could be as well done just by a human being.

The additional disadvantage (or advantage, depends how you look at it) of this approach (as well as of UUIDv1) would be, that you'd know where the ticket has been created as well as order of the tickets within one system.